# Clickable URL gets segmented by the new line?

Tags: urls

In my reference, I have a clickable link. It is cut into two lines automatically.

Problem comes when I click it. When I click it, the part in the 2nd line is not included. I am directed to the non-sense `http://www`

**How can I fix it?**

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the BibTeX entry?  Also, which `\bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: In fact, a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be best. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you loading `hyperref`?

Comment: @egreg Nope. Should I?

Comment: @FarticlePilter Yes; without `hyperref` the links are only guessed at by the PDF viewer.